# mininet-wifi cant support normal OVSSwitch in Mobile Node mobility scenario?

Tags: python, sdn, mobility, onos

I want to programme a python script to support MN mobility in SDN network using mininet-wifi . And Mininet-WIFI support addAccessPoint() method and so on . **But when I add normal ovsswitch (for example addSwitch('s1') ) ,the remote controller ONOS cant detect the s1** .It only detect the APs. I donnnot know why?

I want to build a topology like this : h1 linked s1 ,s1 linked s2 and ap1, s2 linked s1 ,h2 and ap2 .sta1 linked ap1 using wireless link and sta2 linked ap2 using wireless link.  The question is that ONOS controller cannot detect s1 and s2 so that between every two node cannot ping successfully.
I need help ,thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I have get the answer :
    Both switch and AP have the same ID number and consequently the same DPID
(s1, s2, ap1 and ap2). and we can change the ID of APs to ap3 and ap4.